# Invalid operation of opcode and operands

Tags: assembly

I just started learning assembly, so this is, without doubt, a stupid question, but I still can't figure it out. I'm trying to write a procedure that would print the given 16-bit word in hex.

I figured that I could divide it into 4-bit chunks by shifting left and right, and then use it as an index to copy symbol constant from prepared table to output variable. Here how my code looks right now:

```
; Print hex at AX
print_hex:
    pusha
    mov cx, 0                   ; iterator CX = 0
    print_hex_loop:
        mov dx, bx              ; DX = symbol index
        shl dx, cx              ; Loose more significant digits << ERROR
        shr dx, 3               ; Loose less significant digits
        add dx, HEX_TABLE       ; DX = table address
        add cx, HEX_OUT + 2     ; CX = output address
        mov byte [cx], [dx]     ; HEX_OUT[cx] = HEX_TABLE[dx] << ERROR
        sub cx, HEX_OUT + 2     ; CX = iterator
        add cx, 1               ; increase iterator CX
        cmp cx, 4               ; if iterator CX less then 4
        jb print_hex_loop       ; repeat loop
    mov ax, HEX_OUT
    call print_string_loop
    popa
    ret

HEX_TABLE:  db '0123456789abcdef'
HEX_OUT:    db '0x0000', 0
```

However, I get errors that I don't quite understand on shl and mov lines:

```
utility.asm:23: error: invalid combination of opcode and operands
utility.asm:27: error: invalid combination of opcode and operands
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It would be easier if you indicated which lines were 23 & 27.

Comment: @JamesCurran there are `<< ERROR` signs at their ends

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
shl dx, cx              ; Loose more significant digits << ERROR
```

That should be `cl`, not `cx`

```
mov byte [cx], [dx]     ; HEX_OUT[cx] = HEX_TABLE[dx] << ERROR
```

Memory to memory operations are generally not supported by the CPU. You must do this in a two-step operation - load from memory location to register, then store from register to (other) memory location.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was able to solve the first error, easily, but the second one confuses me. After a few experiments, I found out that `mov ax, [bx]` is absolutely correct, but `mov ax, [dx]` gives an `invalid effective address` error. Why? Aren't dx and bx equal?

Comment: It's been a long time since I coded in 16-bit land, but I seem to recall that not all registers can be used for indexing in that mode. You might want to try `si` rather than `dx`.

Comment: @golergka In 16-bit mode addresses are of form `[displacement + bx|bp + si|di]`. You can only use bx or bp for base and si or di for index.